# prove that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a $n\in N$ such that the prime gap $g_n = p_{n+1} - p_n$ > N.

Tags: number-theory

prove that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a $n\in N$ such that the prime gap $g_n = p_{n+1} - p_n$ > N.

I tried using induction but i can't seem to get it right. Are there any other tricks to try solving this problem rather than proof with induction?

for $N = 1$ we can obviously take $n = 2$, for we get $p_3 - p_2 = 5-3 = 2 > 1$

suppose it's true for m numbers, is it than true for m+1? I don't seem to understand how to go further here....

Kees

Comment: The prime number theorem implies that $p_n$ is asymptotically $n \ln(n)$; if your result were false then it could only be asymptotically at most $n$ (more specifically, the upper bound would be something like $Nn$). So that's a "fly with a sledgehammer" proof.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Simple_observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the sequence

$$\{N!+2,N!+3,\cdots,N!+N-1,N!+N\}$$

We have for $k\in\{2,\cdots,N\},\,k|N!+k$, so all the numbers in the above set are composite number so if $p_n$ is the largest prime $\lt N!+2$ and $p_{n+1}$ the next prime $p_{n+1}\gt N!+N$ and so $p_{n+1}-p_n\geq N$

Comment: is there not a possibility that $N-2< p_{n+1}-p_{n} < N$ ?

Comment: $p_{n+1}\geq N!+N+1$ and $p_n\leq N!+1$ so $-p_n\geq -N!-1$. If we add the first and the third inequality we get $p_{n+1}-p_n\geq N$

Answer (score 3):

Take $(n+1)!+2$, $(n+1)!+3$, ..., $(n+1)!+(n+1)$. These are $n$ consecutive numbers, and all of them all are composite, because $(n+1)!+k$ is divisble by $k$ if $2\leq k\leq n+1$.